# Export same package from multiple projects to a single jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, jar

Let us say , I have many projects in eclipse which are dependent on each other.
And some of these projects have a common thread and hence they have files under a common package, say foo.bar

I would like to export all the classes under foo.bar package ONLY, from all those projects (which contain that package) into a single jar file.

What is the best approach to get this accomplished, creating an ant target ? or using maven? or using eclipse ?

Comment: I think it would be preferable to move those classes into a common project and build the common jar(s) in that project.

Comment: I used ant to get the job done.  Thanks @sudocode for your suggestion